# What's the problem of keyBy and sum twice

Tags: scala, apache-flink

Bellow is the simple code I wrote:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

val list = new ListBuffer[Tuple3[String,Int,Int]]

val random = new Random()

for(x <- 0 to 4){
  if(random.nextBoolean()){
    list.append(("INSERT",2,1))
  } else {
    list.append(("UPDATE",2,1))
  }
}


val data = env.fromElements(list).flatMap(_.toList)


val keyed = data.keyBy(0).sum(1)

keyed.print()

val reKeyed = keyed.keyBy(0).sum(2)
reKeyed.print()

env.execute()
```

The dataStream ***reKeyed*** should regard ***keyed*** as input datasource. However, the printed results show that they are from the original data source.
If the second time just call *KeyBy* without calling the *sum* method,
the result of the print is corrent.
So, what's the problem?

Comment: Could you add the expected and the actual output?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you call `keyBy` twice, the second call will overwrite the first one, so the elements may end up on different TaskManagers than previously.
For the case, You are talking about You actually want to use `DataStreamUtils.reinterpretAsKeyedStream`, which should work exactly as You describe, that means it should not change the partitioning of the previously keyed `Datastream`.

Comment: But why is there such an overwrite phenomenon? And the key value used for both KeyBy is the same

Comment: I modified my code as you said,unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything wrong with the given snippet and suspect that you have expectations that don't match with the API.

I added some print statements to the source and to the first and second grouped summation.

```
source:1> (UPDATE,2,1)
source:1> (INSERT,2,1)
source:1> (UPDATE,2,1)
source:1> (UPDATE,2,1)
source:1> (INSERT,2,1)
first:3> (UPDATE,2,1)
first:2> (INSERT,2,1)
first:3> (UPDATE,4,1)
first:2> (INSERT,4,1)
first:3> (UPDATE,6,1)
second:2> (INSERT,2,1)
second:3> (UPDATE,2,1)
second:2> (INSERT,2,2)
second:3> (UPDATE,2,2)
second:3> (UPDATE,2,3)
```

As you can see the random input consists of 3 update and 2 insert statements. So the result of the first `keyBy` correctly shows `update,6,1` and `insert,4,1`.

Now that result is used as an input for the second `keyBy`, but because you are summing on the second column, the results of your first operation is discarded. You'd probably would expect the "final" summation of the first `keyBy` to be taken as the base record where the second column is summed. But it's actually always the first record that is taken as the base, which is the only plausible choice in a streaming setting.

What you actually want to have is a summation of the both fields in the same group by. The streaming API unfortunately has no shortcut for that, but it's quite easy to implement yourself.

```
val keyed = data.keyBy(0)
    .reduce((tuple1, tuple2) => (tuple1._1, tuple1._2 + tuple2._2, tuple1._3 + tuple2._3))

keyed.print("first")
```

That produces

```
source:4> (INSERT,2,1)
source:4> (INSERT,2,1)
source:4> (INSERT,2,1)
source:4> (UPDATE,2,1)
source:4> (INSERT,2,1)
first:3> (UPDATE,2,1)
first:2> (INSERT,2,1)
first:2> (INSERT,4,2)
first:2> (INSERT,6,3)
first:2> (INSERT,8,4)
```

This solution is also more efficient as grouping data is quite expensive.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you mean.But, I wonder why the first-stage summed result has been discarded  becase of  as the base input of second-stage sum operation.

Comment: In  a datapipe, the output of each operator can be used as the input of 
 any others. This is what apache spark does, and so does apache storm.

Comment: That could work in a batch system, but not in a streaming system as the intermediate output is never complete in unbounded inputs. Thus, the second stage would a) wait indefinitely and b) the intermediate result may become arbitrary big.
It would be a different story if you had windows. If you only have bounded inputs, you could use the dataset API to come closer to what you want.

Comment: Btw even if spark streaming uses microbatches, it would still not be able to execute your query as you would like it to be as the "final" result of stage 1 may arrive in the second batch and it would need to start aggregating results in stage 2 as soon as the first batch arrives. If you think of Spark (without streaming), then you probably don't need streaming at all.

Comment: I used to  make it success by spark streaming operator mapWithState or spark structured streaming mode UPDATE.  I don't think it is achievable.